# .Net 4.5 has been installed but still getting ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" error

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, iis-8

So I'm trying to set up a site on AWS EC2 and I followed the steps here:

http://martinbuberl.com/blog/deploy-aspnet-mvc-on-amazon-ec2-with-web-deploy/

The issue I'm getting is the HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error that the tutorial stated but checking my server manager both the .NET Extensibility 3.5 and ASP.NET 4.5 are already installed. Not really sure what I have to do. Web deploy installed them. Do I have to re install it?

Btw, it's currently using IIS 8 on a windows server 2012.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I've stepped through my tutorial again and was able to deploy without a problem.

Two things that come to mind:

- Navigate to **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319**, execute `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` and restart your server to register that ASP.NET version manually with IIS.
- If you didn't deploy a new **ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application** but an already existing project of yours, you most likely are missing an IIS feature on your server.